# expressing a boolean function in another way

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, equation

The following boolean expression is given:

g(p,q,r) = ((p->q') -> r)

Depict this boolean function only by using the operations ∧ (AND), v (OR), ¬ (NEGATION).

How can I do this?

I thought I could replace just the q' with ¬q, so:

g(p,q,r) = ((p -> ¬q) -> r)

But i have no idea, how to replace the implication symbols.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols

Comment: the link does not really help me

Comment: why not -> = →....

Comment: http://mypage.iu.edu/~edizquie/Q250Fall2012/Excercises/Unit1Exam.Answers.pdf

Comment: "why not -> = →...": there is just the definition of implication

Comment: Did you read the rules of Inference? in 2nd link

Comment: e,g, If you know A→B, and you know ¬B, you can conclude ¬A. 
 . . .   **Law of syllogism** If you know A→B, and you know B→C, you can conclude A→C

Comment: so from g(p,q,r) = ((p -> ¬q) -> r) I can conclude : p ->r ? or ¬r ->( ¬¬ q -> ¬p)) =

Comment: and ¬¬q = q ...

Comment: @lightsodium you know that  \$ p \Rightarrow q \equiv \neg p \vee q\$ use it altogether with DeMorgan’s laws. It's simple.

Comment: Use mention feature to notify the person, else they won't notice your message in their inbox. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 1):

((p∧¬q)∧¬r)

or

(p AND NOT q) AND NOT r

Comment: You could improve the answer by explaining the process.